# Need to dynamically set locale for Kendo-Ui-Dateicker component

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In an existing angular application we have utilized a locale service, which sets a locale based on a dropdown's selected value. This locale service is from the [angular-l10n](https://github.com/robisim74/angular-l10n) library.

Recently Kendo-UI for angular was purchased.  We believed that we could hook the datepicker and other internationalization up to this language dropdown (or even the l10n locale service).  So far I have not found anyway to hook or subscribe to the service or dropdown.

I don't really know where else to look.

Kendo-UI documentation accomplishes this by setting the LD_Locale from @angular/core, but from what I have read, this is a const and cannot be update after init.

Any ideas or help as to how to get kendo to internationalize date formats based on a drop down?

Comment: Have a look at the `CldrIntlService`, you can extend this class and inject your own implementation ([Documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/internationalization/services/#toc-customizing-the-default-service)). We are using this approach to switch the displayed locale at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the Kendo components for Angular depends on the `LOCALE_ID` injection token to determine what is the chosen culture setting. Due to the static behavior of Angular DI, this token cannot be updated after bootstrap and you will need to have a dedicated module for each culture. The module will define specific provider for the LOCALE_ID:

```
providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de' }]
```

Here is a demo that uses this approach: http://plnkr.co/edit/tBWDLziqXRrslupopojY?p=info

The other option (as Philipp mentioned in his comment) is to use custom implementation of the IntlService class, which will not depend on the `LOCALE_ID` token. Documentation link can be found below:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/internationalization/services/#toc-customizing-the-default-service

The 3rd option that will be available soon is to define the culture at component level (still under consideration whether it will be a service or an input property). More details can be found in this Github issue:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1009

To sum up,
although `LOCALE_ID` token cannot be modified dynamically, the culture can be updated dynamically with one of the aforementioned approaches.

Comment: Trying the second option: I followed the documentation and forked the kendo plunk.  It worked initally but when i tried to break out the datepicker and the language dropdown to their own modules it stopped working. see this plunk (http://plnkr.co/edit/9mOcpq?p=preview).. As long as the language and datepicker component were in the same module it worked fine.

Comment: I got it working in a plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/BTF3HvJJgFWrm2rbqCjB?p=preview) but when I try and impliment this locally i get a TS error message "Property 'localeId' does not exist on type 'IntlService' ".  Any Ideas?

Comment: Great! Your last approach will work if there is only one root provider for IntlService (which in most cases will be fine).
As to the TS error, IntlService doesn't have `localeId` property. You will need to cast the `this.intl` to either `CldrIntlService` or `any` (unsafe) - `(< CldrIntlService>this.intl).localeId = ...`

Comment: I prepared plunker which uses diff locales with lazily loaded modules - http://plnkr.co/edit/phR0Y7JdfXCjk23MeGIY?p=preview . If you think that this demo is useful, I'll update my answer enhancing it with this approach.

Comment: Sorry it has taken me so long to reply.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to get either example working in our site.  I am at a loss for what to do now...

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr demo that demonstrate the issue? We need smth to work with.

Comment: We are in a similar situation. Updating the locale was no problem and works fine. But we would like to define custom messages (<kendo-calendar-messages today="{{'today' | trans}}"></kendo-calendar-messages>) which would use our translation pipe for dynamic language switch. The datepicker however does not get updated once initialized. Any way to force an update ?